# How do i determine the correct filesystem path

Tags: clojure, path, leiningen, ring, contextpath

I am working on an application that has to download some external resources and make them accessible through a `public/static` directory in Ring.

But.. I have a problem saving the resources into a static directory in my application, when developing I use the `ring-jetty-adapter`; the test & production servers are running Tomcat.

I added `:web-content "public"` to my leiningen project and added the `public` directory in the root of the project, then I have a download function using http-agent and duck-streams:

```clj
(defn download
  [file-name url]
  (h/http-agent url
                :handler (fn [agnt]
                           (let [fname file-name]
                             (with-open [w (d/writer fname)]
                               (d/copy (h/stream agnt) w))))))
```

If I am booting Jetty from the REPL and use `savepath: "public/my.file"`, the downloaded file is placed correctly in the `public` directory.
But when I deploy it using a `.war` file to Tomcat, it looks for a `public` directory in the Tomcat root directory, and not under the application context path.

I tried to add a middleware wrapper to determine the context path and from there build the correct save path, but I cannot find any way to access the `HttpServlet` or a way to determine if the application is running in the adapter or if it is deployed under a specific context.

Here the wrapper:

```
(defn wrap-context-info [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (let [resp (handler req)]
      (assoc resp :servlet (:servlet req) :req (:servlet-request  req)))))
```

both `:servlet` and `:req` are `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [ring-servlet source](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/0.3.4/ring-servlet/src/ring/util/servlet.clj#L49-53), it appears that the ring servlet adapter associates the `HttpServlet`, `HttpServletRequest`, and `HttpServletResponse` objects with the ring request map under `:servlet`, `:servlet-request`, and `:servlet-response` keys, accordingly.

It also adds a `:servlet-context` entry to the request map with the value of `(.getServletContext servlet)` for convenience.

Inside your handler, you might want to check for the presence of these keys in the request map, and then pull further information that you need from the associated objects.

Comment: well this is what i try to do:

Comment: (defn wrap-context-info [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (let [resp (handler req)]
      (assoc resp :servlet (:servlet req) :req (:servlet-request  req)))))